# How to encode tuple as output parameter to function using web3j in java

Tags: java, tuples, web3-java

```
struct AccountReaderResult {
    int256 cash;
    int256 position;
    int256 availableMargin;
    int256 margin;
    int256 settleableMargin;
    bool isInitialMarginSafe;
    bool isMaintenanceMarginSafe;
    bool isMarginSafe;
    int256 targetLeverage;
}

function getAccountStorage(
    address liquidityPool,
    uint256 perpetualIndex,
    address account
) public returns (bool isSynced, AccountReaderResult memory accountStorage) {
    try ILiquidityPool(liquidityPool).forceToSyncState() {
        isSynced = true;
    } catch {
        isSynced = false;
    }
    (bool success, bytes memory data) =
        liquidityPool.call(
            abi.encodeWithSignature(
                "getMarginAccount(uint256,address)",
                perpetualIndex,
                account
            )
        );
    require(success, "fail to retrieve margin account");
    accountStorage = _parseMarginAccount(data);
}
```

The above is the smart contract code.

```
public RemoteCall<List<Type>> getAccountStorage(String liquidityPool, BigInteger perpetualIndex, String account) {
    final Function function = new Function(
            "getAccountStorage",
            Arrays.<Type>asList(new Address(liquidityPool),
                    new Uint256(perpetualIndex), new Address(account)),
            Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(new TypeReference<Bool>() {}, new TypeReference<Utf8String>() {}));
    return executeRemoteCallMultipleValueReturn(function);
}
```

This is the java code corresponding to the smart contract, which needs to be called using web3j. Now I encounter the return value of struct type, I don't know how to receive it in java.
The above java code returns a parameter error, how should I receive this tuple type parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I hope it isn't too late...

1. The function in contract. It is important to be as "view".

```
function get(uint _id) public view returns (string memory content, uint id) {
    Oferta storage oferta = ofertas[_id];
    return (oferta.content, oferta.id);
}
```

We have 2 values in the return: "content" (string) and "id" (integer).

2. Your code in Java wrapper is like mine:
   Here I return Utf8String and Uint256.

```
private RemoteCall<List<Type>> get(BigInteger _id) {
    final org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Function function = new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Function(
            "get", 
            Arrays.<Type>asList(new org.web3j.abi.datatypes.Uint(_id)), 
            Arrays.<TypeReference<?>>asList(  
                new TypeReference<Utf8String>() {}, 
                new TypeReference<Uint256>() {}   
            ));   
    return executeRemoteCallMultipleValueReturn(function);
}
```

3. Now the trick. Do not use it directly. Use another function to convert to a POJO.

```
public static class Oferta {
    public String content;
    public BigInteger id;
}

public Oferta getOferta( BigInteger _id ) {
    Oferta of = new Oferta();
    try {
        List<Type> res = get(_id).send( );
        of.content = ((Utf8String)res.get(0)).getValue();
        of.id = ((Uint256)res.get(1)).getValue();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return of;
}
```

Note the casting from the result array. Respect the parameter index order.